# Eject (not unmount) USB devices via terminal (SSH), and redetect a USB device after ejecting

Tags: command-line, mount, osx, disk

This is a macOS question (Unix), and since Ask Different doesn't have many savvy terminal users I am asking here.

Other than right click the device and select eject (this is not unmount, because it completely delete the device in `diskutil`), and then replug the device, is there a way to do this via terminal?

For example, if I eject a USB Mass Storage device, it will be removed from `diskutil list` output. I can find it again via `ioreg -p IOUSB -l -w 0` with output as such:

```
Mass Storage@1d160000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000009d8, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1 ms), retain 14>
{
    "sessionID" = 8439571007835
    "iManufacturer" = 1
    "bNumConfigurations" = 1
    "idProduct" = 25479
    "bcdDevice" = 262
    "Bus Power Available" = 250
    "USB Address" = 2
    "bMaxPacketSize0" = 64
    "iProduct" = 2
    "iSerialNumber" = 3
    "bDeviceClass" = 0
    "Built-In" = No
    "locationID" = 487981056
    "bDeviceSubClass" = 0
    "bcdUSB" = 512
    "USB Product Name" = "Mass Storage"
    "PortNum" = 6
    "non-removable" = "no"
    "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"9dc7b780-9ec0-11d4-a54f-000a27052861"="IOUSBFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOUSBLib.bundle"}
    "bDeviceProtocol" = 0
    "IOUserClientClass" = "IOUSBDeviceUserClientV2"
    "IOPowerManagement" = {"DevicePowerState"=0,"CurrentPowerState"=3,"CapabilityFlags"=65536,"MaxPowerState"=4,"DriverPowerState"=3}
    "kUSBCurrentConfiguration" = 1
    "Device Speed" = 2
    "USB Vendor Name" = "Generic"
    "idVendor" = 1423
    "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
    "USB Serial Number" = "29FEA949"
    "IOClassNameOverride" = "IOUSBDevice"
}
```